# git fork a repo content into branch of another repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

Say there is a repo A with just a branch master.There is another repo which is fork of repo A.This repo is called B.
B's master branch has certain new commits but is far behind the repo A.
I have to make a new branch in repo B with the contents of master branch of A.
I will have to pull in latest changes from repo A from time to time into this new branch.
I have cloned repo A to my computer, made some changes.Now this has to go to the new branch of B over github.
How do I do this ?
I tried looking at other questions but couldn't grasp it being a git newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch master-of-a
git fetch upstream master:master-of-a
```

I would not do it like that if I were you, though. I would work, in B, in branches only. And I would synchronize A's master branch to B's master branch. It's much more traditional, and less confusing, to have the two master branches contain the same thing.

If you submit the changes made in one of B's branches and it ends up being accepted in repo A, then it will be merged to A's master branch, and you can then just synchronize B's master branch with A's, and delete the accepted branch.

Comment: Execute `git fetch upstream master:master-of-a` again. It gets all the changes from the branch master of upstream and applies then on your local branch master-of-a.